# Color a radius of patches Netlogo

Tags: netlogo, patch

im trying to show a cultivation process. At setup im creating the farmers and giving them a random farm size (with the splotch) then, at go, im telling them that if they have enought money all patches near them that are the splotch turn into green, representing cultivation. But its just changing one pixel and not all round it. It most be someting small but i cant see it. Thanks in advance for the help
.

````
breed [cercas cerca]
breed [medios medio]
breed [lejos lejo]

patches-own[calidad 
  cercanialago
  cultivado
]
turtles-own [ingresos
  gastos] 
create-cercas 10 + random 10
 
 [ set size 1        ;; easier to see
    set color 135
setxy random xcor random ycor
move-to one-of patches with [not any? other turtles in-radius 3 and pcolor = 57]
    set heading random 45 + 45
    set ingresos 1000000 + random 6000000
   
 ]  
  
ask turtles
  [ ask patches in-radius (1 + random 3)    
    [ set pcolor 35 ] ]



to go
  
  ask cercas [
    ifelse ingresos > 2000000 [if any? patches in-radius 4 with [pcolor = 35] [if ticks mod 3 = 0 [set pcolor 62]  ]]
      []
  ] ```
````

Comment: welcome to stack! may I suggest that in the future, you translate your variables into english before you post? this makes it easier to understand your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `cercas` are a breed of turtles.

A useful feature of NetLogo is that any turtle can directly read and modify the variables of the patch it is on (i.e. without the need to invoke such patch).

So when you ask a turtle to `set pcolor 62`, it will automatically refer to `pcolor` of the patch it is on.

If we eliminate all of the conditions from your last block of commands, we have:
`ask cercas [set pcolor 62]`. This is what you are asking `cercas` to do: simply changing the `pcolor` of the patch they are on.

The fact that you use `patches in-radius 4` in the condition for the first `if` statement does not influence the `ask cercas [set pcolor 62]` part. The condition is one thing, the command to be executed if the condition holds true is a separate thing.

Therefore you should make cercas `ask patches in-radius 4` to change their pcolors.

Comment: Matteo nice to see you again! But i need to fist ask the turtles for Ingresos, if they have have it all brown patches near that turtle must change.

Comment: But now the ticks are changing instantly instead of changing every 3 ticks, or any selected amount.

Comment: @bksnlow Do you mean the patches are changing at every tick instead of every 3 ticks? You still need to apply all the conditions you want to check for (the one for `ingresos`, the one for the patches' colors, the one for `ticks mod 3 = 0` etc). The only part you need to modify is the last block, leave all of your conditions untouched

Comment: I add everything but the color is Changing at 2 tick not 3, which is strange. Even if i do like ticks mod 10 it changes at 2. Ill have to check if i messed up somewhere else. Thanks for the help again!